# How to solve librustdoc.so missing when using rustbook tool?

Tags: linux, rust

I've used

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/steveklabnik/rustbook.git
```

to install rustbook successfully, but when I run `rustbook` I get an error:

```
rustbook: error while loading shared libraries: librustdoc-c0dcaea09a16c7ec.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But I can find out this .so file.

```
./.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustdoc-c0dcaea09a16c7ec.so
./.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustdoc-c0dcaea09a16c7ec.so
```

How can I let `rustbook` know the path to `librustdoc-c0dcaea09a16c7ec.so`?

- rustc 1.16.0-nightly (4ecc85beb 2016-12-28)
- rustdoc 1.16.0-nightly (4ecc85beb 2016-12-28)

`rustup show`:

```
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.16.0-nightly (4ecc85beb 2016-12-28)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue with rustup ([#350](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/350), [#765](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/765)), specifically around cargo-installed binaries that were compiled against the nightly toolchain. If your application requires nightly to even compile, there's not much you can do other than `rustup run nightly myprogram`. This will start the program with the appropriate environment.

If the application doesn't require nightly Rust, then install it using the stable toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

List the directory containing your shared library into `/etc/ld.so.conf`, or make a symlink from a path already listed there, or from `/usr/lib` (`/usr/local/lib` would be preferable, but maybe you have to add it to the list in `ld.so.conf`, so this would be again case 1).

Comment: While this is a generic answer that will probably stop the error from occurring, it should not be required to perform these actions to solve this specific problem.

Comment: The first tag was 'linux', the second was 'rust' which I don't even know. Your answer is clearly the correct one, but perhaps the tag order should have been 'rust' then 'linux'.

Comment: Perhaps, but tag order is by number of tags, so there's no way to specify.